# loading javascript functions returned from an ajax request (named functions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to load javascript functions from a view generated from an ajax request.  Thus far I have looked all over the internet and found this `eval()` function, however, I need to load named functions to memory to be called on events made by the newly added html.  Does anyone know what method to use or how to accomplish this?

**Note:** The only way I can think of is to include the returned javascript functions in the page itself (and not return them along with the html), however, I would like to avoid this if possible.

**Note Update:** I can't include it on the app.blade.php because the ajax request needs to add in a few variables set at the time of the ajax request before the client receives the ajax response.  Thus, the only method to accomplishing my objective is to somehow load my newly added scripts to the client buffer.

When the ajax request runs, it returns something like this:

```
<script>
    function somefunction(){
        //some stuff
    }
</script>

<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="somefunction();">sometext</a>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: **"I am attempting to load javascript functions from a view"** - show us this attempt and we can guess better.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid Edited.  Everything works except I cannot run the added functions on the page, however, once you run the function, every page shows the exact same thing that is loaded in this ajax request without problems.  I just get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: somefunction is not defined" in console.

Comment: Just so I can help, why do you need to add functions on the fly. Is there a reason you can't create a JS file with various utility functions that you can call through dynamically generated html? This is assuming you're not letting the user create their own JS functions, where as then it'd make sense why you'd need to add these later in the lifecycle

Comment: I am creating an instant messenger where, when the user views another user's profile and clicks 'message', a window pops up (this is where the ajax request comes in which includes variables server side).  My problem resides with the fact that when the window pops up, the javascript functions that come along with it do not work.  The window, however, DOES work on every other view (when you click the link it sets a session variable which makes the window pull up on every page thereafter until you close it).